# Spring / Jhipster QueryService filter with many to many relation

Tags: spring-boot, filter, spring-data-jpa, jhipster, criteria

I'm using QueryService generated with Jhispter, and I'm trying to use them to filter a list of list.

It works fine when I filter on fields of this entity, but now I have to do something a bit more complicated.

I have this data set :
student <----- the entity I was talking about above and it has a list of classrooms
class Room <----- which has a list of students

*student class*

```
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private Set<ClassRoom> classRooms = new HashSet<>();
```

*ClassRoom class*

```
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(
        name = "rel_class_room__student",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "class_room_id"  , referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"  , referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
```

What I have to do is :

Filter students that assigned to any classroom
Filter student that not assigned to any classroom

in case of filter with student assigned to classroom
i need to pass the expression of what i need to the root something like this

- in StudentQueryService class*

```
 // filter by className id 
if (criteria.getClassRoomId() != null) {
                specification = specification.and(
                        buildSpecification(
                                criteria.getClassRoomId(),
                                root -> root.join(Student_.classRooms, JoinType.LEFT).get(ClassRoom_.id)));
            }
  
 // serch by assigned to classRoom or not
            if (criteria.getIsAssignedToClassroom() != null && criteria.getIsAssignedToClassroom().equals(true)) {

    //  TODO check if the student assigned to classroom
               }
```

note i don't have a specific classroom to check if the student assigned to it or not so it should be all exists classrooms in database